# CSS property support

Tags: css, browser

Is there a way to check if a CSS property that I'm going to use is supported by the common browsers? So that I can avoid using *-moz* and *-webkit* prefixed properties, if the unprefixed property is supported commonly by the browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are many answer out there you can check

for checking browser compatibility
1) [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp)
or directly you can use 
1) [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a service like: http://caniuse.com/ for quick referencing.

Answer (score 1):

http://csslint.net/ provides compatibility warnings. Whether this does what you need I couldn't say but it may be helpful.